# How to separate rows in a table with space between with HTML and Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, datatables, bootstrap-5

I currently have a table with my content in but it looks like
[image: How it currently looks]
I would like it to have space between each row to make them distinctively separate and look something like this

[image: What I would like it to look like]

I have tried using padding on my td elements and border spacing on my tr elements. What would be the easiest way to do this within bootstrap 5? Below is my HTML and CSS

```css
.icon-green {
  color: green;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 15px;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">10001</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">10002</td>
    <td>Sally</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">10003</td>
    <td>Emma</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are limited things you can do with tr elements. You can use `box-shadow` and `outline` on them as below. Note, I've had to add a class to your table so I can increase the specificity of the rule that causes the table not to collapse.

```css
.icon-green {
  color: green;
}

/* note the added class, if you use just 'table' as the selector bootstrap will override it and collapse your table */
table.mytable {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 15px;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  outline: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0px #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

<table class='mytable'>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">10001</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">10002</td>
    <td>Sally</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">10003</td>
    <td>Emma</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you already fixed most of your own problem except that because everything is white, it's hard to see that there is space between the rows. Added a slight box shadow on the rows. I'm not sure how you are using bootstrap here though, but I assume it's similar if you want to override bootstrap styles

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px 15px;
}

tr{
   /* only added this line */
    box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.142);
}

th,
td {

    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td">10001</td>
      <td>Tom</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td">10002</td>
      <td>Sally</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td">10003</td>
      <td>Emma</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```